# bring text closer in a div

Tags: css

I have written a loop in wordpress that loops through the post titles and then displays the first 6 in a special latest news section on top of the page. The problem is that i cannot bring the headings closer as you can see in image 1. I want these titles to appear as shown in image 2.

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

Here's my HTML and PHP code:

```
<div id="freshlyWrapper">
<div id="freshlyposts">
<?php
$freshlyIonised = new WP_Query();
$freshlyIonised->query('category_name=featured&showposts=6');
while($freshlyIonised->have_posts()):
$freshlyIonised->the_post();
?>
<div class="freshlyionisedbox"><h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3></div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
#freshlyWrapper {
    width: 980px;
    text-align: left;
    background: #ffffff;
    float: left;
}

#freshlyposts {
    width: 980px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
    height: 100px;
    color: #000000;
}
    
.freshlyionisedbox {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    height: 25px;
    margin-left: 140px;
    padding: 0px;
    top: 3px;
}

#freshlyposts h3 {
    width: auto;
    font-weight: normal;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.clearboth { clear: both; }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.freshlyionisedbox {
     position: relative;
     float:left;
     height: 25px;
     margin-left: 40px;
    /*-- try it --*/
     padding:0px;
     top: 3px;
}
```

Comment: @hackre: thanks, just whant to edit my answer, but you are faster ;)

Comment: @hakre: Try not to edit an answer right after it's been posted. The answerer will often edit it within the 5 minute grace period.

Comment: @thirtydot: Will keep that in mind. Thanks for the hint. @Arthur Halma: sorry, was just spotting it and quickly on the edit link ;)